# book a user id with a role (instructor) whilst logged in as a user as a role of (admin or student)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to book an instructor whilst logged in as a student (user).
log in MODEL is User with optional roles of [Instructor] [Student] [Admin].

I keep getting this error

undefined method `id' for #
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgyoe.jpg)
The button is giving me the error..

How do I declare the instructors user_id to be booked whilst logged in as a user such as student

**instructors_controller.rb**

```
# GET /instructors
# GET /instructors.json
def index
  #@instructors = Instructor.all
   @instructor_users = User.where(role: 'instructor')
end
```

**Instructor/index**

```
<h1>List Instructors</h1>

<table>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Role</th>
</tr>

<% @instructor_users.each do |user| %>

  <tr>
  <td><%= user.id %></td>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
  <td><%= user.role %></td>
  <td>
  <%= button_to 'Book a Lesson', {controller: 'lessons', action: 'new', id: @user.id } , {class: "button-to"} %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>


<br>
```

**lessons_controller.rb**

```
def new
    if logged_in?
    #@lesson = Lesson.new
    @lesson = Lesson.new(user_id: params[:id], name: User.find(session[:user_id]).name  

    session[:return_to] = nil       
else            
    session[:return_to] = request.url           
    redirect_to login_path, alert: " 'You need to login to book a lesson' " 
end
end



# POST /lessons
# POST /lessons.json
def create
@lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)
  if @lesson.save
      instructor = User.find(@instructor.user.id)
      redirect_to lesson, notice: 'Lesson was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

> @instructor_user.id

to

> user.id

because  `@instructor_users.each do |user| to user`

Comment: <%= button_to 'Book a Lesson', {controller: 'lessons', action: 'new', id: user.id } , {class: "button-to"} %> i was talking about this user.id did u change it here?

Comment: Yes I have, it still came error.. perhaps the controller ids are wrong to

Comment: can u write exact errror line here

Comment: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

line 17:  <%= button_to 'Book a Lesson', {controller: 'lessons', action: 'new', id: @user.id } , {class: "button-to"} %>

line 10:     <% @instructor_users.each do |user| %>

Comment: why u still have @user.id ..it must be user.id without @

Comment: dont forget to change question to asnwered :) Good day

Comment: I am new to this, how do I do that?

Comment: You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).